# How to do a contour graph of a conditional function with two variables?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, graph, conditional-statements

I want to do a contour graph of a conditional function, but I am getting an error. 
This is the code:

```
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
a1=15.8
a2=18.3
a3=0.714
a4=23.2
def bindingenergy(Z,A):
    if A%2==1:
        a5=0
    elif A%2==0 and Z%2==0:
        a5=12
    else:
        a5=-12
    B=a1*A-a2*A**(2/3)-a3*((Z**2)/A**(1/3))-a4*(((A-2*Z)**2)/A)+(a5/A**(1/2))
    C=B/A
    return C
s=np.arange(1,300)
t=np.arange(1,100)
X, Y=np.meshgrid(t,s)
E=bindingenergy(X,Y)
plt.ion()
plt.contourf(X,Y,E,25, cmap=cm.rainbow)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

When i run the program, I get the error: 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

for the line

```
if A%2==1:
```

I think that I am somehow applying boolean logic to an array(although I dont understand how is this happening), which is the reason for the error, but I have no idea how to rewrite it, so that I can get the contour graph.
I have searched everywhere for an answer, but either didn't understand it or it couldn't be applied to this problem.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: You are correct, the issue is that you are applying boolean logic across an array. In your Python interpreter, suppose you run the following: `Y % 2`. What do you get? So the issue is, what do you want to equal one? *Any* of those values, or *all* of those values? This is why you get the helpful NumPy ValueError: _The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()_.

Comment: From looking at your code, it is a bit hard to follow exactly "what" conditional function you're trying to plot. Could you please respond clarifying what it is you'd like your program to do (more generally)?

Comment: Well, there is only one function. And i said it in the beginning: I want to do a contour graph of that function. And to your first comment: I think that is where  the problem is - I want it to be equal to one for odd values, not for just any values or all values.

Comment: Looks like you can use `a5 = ((A%2==0) * (Z%2==0)) * 12 + ((A%2==0) * (Z%2==1)) * (-12)` and remove all the if/else stuff.

Comment: Nice, that works. But what if I want to limit the function with a cycle, so that it takes the number Z from the t array and doesn't run for all numbers A from the s array, but only for numbers Z-3Z? How do I graph that?